# How to handle a lot of data fetching from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am a beginner. I am trying to get data from an API and list them by using `v-for`. But It is causing a lag. My app is freezing when data comes or when I search for something on my list.
This part of the code is where I fetch data. How to improve that code to have a more fluent app.

```
async created() {
    this.loaded = false;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      data.forEach(element => {
        this.chartData.symbols = [...this.chartData.symbols, element.symbol];
        this.chartData.price = [...this.chartData.price, +element.lastPrice];
      });

      this.loaded = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },
```

My App component:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-row align="center" class="ma-8 pa-6" fluid>
      <!-- Container Start Point For buttons-->
      <div class="mb-6 d-flex justify-start hidden">
        <v-btn @click="toggleButton" depressed color="primary" class="mr-6 btn">
          {{ (btnText = dialog ? 'Add/Update' : 'Add Stock') }}
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn @click="refreshPage" depressed color="primary" class="btn">
          Refresh
        </v-btn>
      </div>
      <!-- Container End Point For Buttons-->

      <!-- Modal Code Starts-->
      <v-dialog
        v-model="dialog"
        width="80%"
        height="900px"
        overflow="hidden"
        pa-6
      >
        <v-card class="pa-12">
          <v-form>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              label="Search"
              outlined
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-row>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(pair, index) in filterBy(pairs, search)"
                :key="pair.symbol"
              >
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title ref="refWord"
                    >{{ pair.symbol }} - {{ pair.price }}</v-list-item-title
                  >
                </v-list-item-content>
                <v-text-field
                  outlined
                  v-model="numberValue"
                  hide-details
                  single-line
                  type="number"
                  class="shrink mr-2"
                  width="50px"
                  height="50px"
                />
                <AddBtn @click-event="searchHandle(index)" />
              </v-list-item>
            </v-row>
          </v-form>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
      <!-- Modal Code Ends-->

      <!-- Horizontal Line-->
      <hr class="line" />

      <!--Mainpage List Starts -->
      <v-col cols="12" sm="5" height="1000px">
        <v-container height="1000px">
          <v-list-item
            class="border"
            v-for="(label, index) in chartData.labels"
            :key="index++"
          >
            <v-row>
              <v-list-item-content d-flex>
                <v-list-item-title
                  >{{ label }}
                  <span>{{
                    chartData.datasets[0].data[index]
                  }}</span></v-list-item-title
                >
              </v-list-item-content>
              <v-btn class="btn" dark md color="error" @click="deleteHandle">
                Delete
              </v-btn>
            </v-row>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-container>
      </v-col>
      <!-- Mainpage List  End-->

      <!-- Vertical Line-->

      <hr class="vertical" />

      <!-- Chart part -->
      <v-col cols="12" sm="5">
        <PieChart
          :data="this.chartData.datasets[0].data"
          :bgColor="this.chartData.datasets[0].backgroundColor"
          :labels="this.chartData.labels"
          :key="this.chartData.labels.length"
        />
      </v-col>
      <!-- Chart part end-->
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import PieChart from './components/PieChart';
import Vue2Filters from 'vue2-filters';
import AddBtn from './components/AddBtn.vue';

export default {
  name: 'App',
  mixins: [Vue2Filters.mixin],

  components: {PieChart, AddBtn},
  methods: {
    toggleButton() {
      this.dialog = !this.dialog;
      // this.btnText = this.dialog ? 'Add / Update' : 'Add Stock';
    },
    searchHandle(index) {
      const [sym, price] = this.$refs.refWord[index].innerText.split('-');
      this.symbol = sym;
      this.chartData.labels = [...this.chartData.labels, sym];
      this.chartData.datasets[0].data = [
        ...this.chartData.datasets[0].data,
        +price,
      ];
    },
    deleteHandle() {
      this.chartData.labels.pop();
      this.chartData.datasets[0].data.pop();
      this.chartData.datasets[0].backgroundColor.pop();
    },
    refreshPage() {
      setTimeout(function () {
        location.reload();
      }, 100);
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    dialog: false,
    search: '',
    btnText: 'Add Stock',
    numberValue: 1,
    chartData: {
      labels: ['CHM', 'BBM', 'LLJTRY'],
      symbols: [],
      price: [],
      datasets: [
        {
          data: [0.035, 0.26, 0.022],
          backgroundColor: [
            '#41B883',
            '#E46651',
            '#20AB2E',
            '#DD1B16',
            '#DD26FF',
            '#9ab973',
            `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`, // Random color
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  }),
  computed: {
    pairs() {
      return this.chartData.symbols.map((symbol, i) => {
        return {
          symbol: symbol,
          price: this.chartData.price[i],
        };
      });
    },
  },
  async created() {
    this.loaded = false;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      data.forEach(element => {
        this.chartData.symbols = [...this.chartData.symbols, element.symbol];
        this.chartData.price = [...this.chartData.price, +element.lastPrice];
      });

      this.loaded = true;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.btn {
  text-transform: none !important;
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
hr.vertical {
  height: 80%;
  margin: 3% auto;
}
.scroller {
  height: 100%;
}
.border {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.123);
  padding: 5px 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
```

PieChart Component:

```
<template>
  <Pie
    v-if="loaded && this.chartData.labels.length !== 0"
    id="my-chart-id"
    :options="chartOptions"
    :data="chartData"
  />
  <Pie v-else :options="chartOptions" :data="emptyChartData"></Pie>
</template>

<script>
import {Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend} from 'chart.js';
import {Pie} from 'vue-chartjs';

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

export default {
  name: 'PieChart',
  components: {Pie},
  props: ['data', 'bgColor', 'labels'],
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [...this.labels],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [...this.data],
            backgroundColor: [...this.bgColor],
          },
        ],
      },
      emptyChartData: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [
          {
            data: [0.01],
            backgroundColor: ['#999797'],
          },
        ],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        elements: {
          arc: {
            borderWidth: 0,
          },
        },
      },
      loaded: true,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

AddBtn component:

```
<template>
  <v-btn class="btn" dark md color="success" @click="$emit('click-event')">
    Add
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style></style>
```

I list API coming data by using v-for.

```
<v-row>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(pair, index) in filterBy(pairs, search)"
                :key="pair.symbol"
              >
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title ref="refWord"
                    >{{ pair.symbol }} - {{ pair.price }}</v-list-item-title
                  >
                </v-list-item-content>
                <v-text-field
                  outlined
                  v-model="numberValue"
                  hide-details
                  single-line
                  type="number"
                  class="shrink mr-2"
                  width="50px"
                  height="50px"
                />
                <AddBtn @click-event="searchHandle(index)" />
              </v-list-item>
            </v-row>
          </v-form>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
```

Comment: https://vueuse.org/core/computedasync/#computedasync

Comment: Or basically anything which does not hang `create`. Create must be sync.

Comment: Tried this but nothing changed. Still freezing.   

```
 fetch('https://api2.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        data.forEach(element => {
          this.chartData.symbols = [...this.chartData.symbols, element.symbol];
          this.chartData.price = [...this.chartData.price, +element.lastPrice];
        });
      });

    this.loaded = true;
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem comes from the overuse of the **spread syntax** (`...`). This is a nice ES6 feature, but you should be very careful when you use it within a loop.

The API you are working with returns more than 2,000 entries and, for each iteration, you are spreading two arrays which are incrementally more complex. This is absolutely not necessary and, of course, it is terrible in terms of performance.

I suggest you to use [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

A simple test using [JSBench.Me](https://jsbench.me/) shows a huge difference between these two strategies:

[image: Spread vs Push]